# Why is the example schematic for TI LM5051 OR'ing controller shown from the negative side?

Tags: schematics

Since voltage potential is simply the potential difference between two rails, it doesn't really make a difference if we draw a network as going from `+Vcc` to `GND` or from `GND` to `-Vcc`. However, the convention is pretty much always to draw seen from the positive side.

However, in the case of TI's [LM5051](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snvs702d/snvs702d.pdf), the technical writers opted to draw it from the negative perspective. From the perspective of a lay reader, this would seem to complicate matters and increase the odds of a mistake. I'm perplexed why they did it this way. I assume there must be a subtle point are they trying to communicate. What is it?

[image]

Comment: `technical writers opted to draw it` ... don't you mean `designers opted to design it`?

Comment: @jsotola, from what I understand, it is unlikely that the technical writers and the designers are the same people.

Comment: it is not up to the technical writers to determine where the ground reference is

Answer (score 1):

Actually. if you read the entire datasheet, you'll see that positive ground is referenced **everywhere**, not just in that schematic. For example, one the first page. it specifies "The LM5051 can connect power supplies ranging from -6V to -100V and can withstand transients up to -100V".

There's a clue in the example schematic that they specify -**48** volt input. It happens the way-back-when, the telephone company standardized on 48 volt power with positive ground! Telecom equipment continues to use -48 volts for DC power to this day.

I think we can imply that this device is designed for telecom applications.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen it was positive ground everywhere, so I guess my question wasn't clear enough. I'm still confused *why* to show it this way, although it sounds like my question my have become "why did the telecom industry settle on -48V?"